# How to find the recurrence relation for the basic operation of algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, recurrence

This an algorithm to count inversions in an array, a divide and conquer algorithm. I want to know what is the basic operation of the this algorithm and how do I set up a recurrence relation to analyze the number of executions of the basic step?

The definition of basic step: The operation contributing the most to the total running time of an algorithm. It is typically the most time consuming operation in the algorithm’s innermost loop.

Examples: Key comparison operation; arithmetic operation (division being the most time-consuming, followed by multiplication).

This is the algorithm

```
  public static int merge(int[] arr, int[] aux, int low, int mid, int high)
    {
        int k = low, i = low, j = mid + 1;
        int inversionCount = 0;
 
        // while there are elements in the left and right runs
        while (i <= mid && j <= high)
        {
            if (arr[i] <= arr[j]) {
                aux[k++] = arr[i++];
            }
            else {
                aux[k++] = arr[j++];
                inversionCount += (mid - i + 1);    // NOTE
            }
        }
 
        // copy remaining elements
        while (i <= mid) {
            aux[k++] = arr[i++];
        }
 
        // no need to copy the second half
 
        // copy back to the original array to reflect sorted order
        for (i = low; i <= high; i++) {
            arr[i] = aux[i];
        }
 
        return inversionCount;
    }
 
    // Sort array `arr[low…high]` using auxiliary array `aux`
    public static int mergeSort(int[] arr, int[] aux, int low, int high)
    {
        // Base case
        if (high == low) {    // if run size == 1
            return 0;
        }
 
        // find midpoint
        int mid = (low + ((high - low) >> 1));
        int inversionCount = 0;
 
        // recursively split runs into two halves until run size == 1,
        // then merges them and return up the call chain
 
        // split/merge left half
        inversionCount += mergeSort(arr, aux, low, mid);
 
        // split/merge right half
        inversionCount += mergeSort(arr, aux, mid + 1, high);
 
        // merge the two half runs
        inversionCount += merge(arr, aux, low, mid, high);
 
        return inversionCount;
    }
```

How do I set up a recurrence relation to analyze number of executions of the basic steps? Please also provide explanation.

Comment: Do you want to know how to calculate its `time complexity`? It will be `O(n*log n)`. I can explain it if that's what you want to know.

Comment: yes can you please explain it! Is it the complexity of the basic operation?

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/merge-sort/a/analysis-of-merge-sort Does this help? There is also a section in there for the analysis of merge operation.